# Jquery transform translate and rotate эффект

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать такой эффект для блоков?

!!Это не реклама, нужна помощь в таком эффекте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в конце блок получает такой стиль

```
style="transform: translate(-670px, -1005px) rotate(-1.0472rad); display: none;"
```

Comment: ссылка не верная: Sorry, we couldn’t find that page

Comment: отредактировал вопрос

Comment: Вопрос - ссылка. добавьте гифку в вопрос. добавление ссылок не дает необходимого эффекта. на мобильном - не посмотреть

Comment: А как попасть в раздел знакомств? Надо регистрироваться?

Comment: исправил вопрос и залил гиф

Comment: С помощью css `transform: translate(-670px, -1005px) rotate(-1.0472rad);`

Comment: да, а как заанимировать, чтобы был такой эффект исчезновения через jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добиться данного эффекта можно с помощью комбинации css `transform` и `transition`.

```js
function changeClass(className) {
  square.classList.add(className);
}

square.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
  square.classList.remove(...square.classList);
});
```

```css
#square {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.decline {
  transform: translate(-100%, -100%) rotate(-1.0472rad);
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}

.accept {
  transform: translate(100%, -100%) rotate(1.0472rad);
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="square"></div>
<button onclick="changeClass('decline')">decline</button>
<button onclick="changeClass('accept')">accept</button>
```

Comment: отлично, спасибо

Comment: а еще такой вопрос, как сделать, чтобы приобретал статус display:none после анимации?

Comment: @Aslero Видите событие `transitionend`? Оно возникает, когда анимация заканчивается. Можете написать любой код туда. Спасибо принимается в виде принятого ответа :)